# How do I create a visual studio database project for oracle database?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, devops, sql-server-data-tools

Using the SSDT tool we can connect to mssql database and create a database project in visual studio and deploy it using the .dacpac file that we get from building the application. Can the same be done for Oracle databases instead of mssql database?

Comment: Hi and welcome! please read this and edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this related to **devops**?

Answer (score 2):

There is something called "[Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html)", but I haven't looked at it in years.